# Detect shutdown signal from docker when using Generic Host IHostBuilder

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

I have a default generic host builder as below:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateDefaultBuilder(string[] args)
{
    var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);

    builder
        .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
        {
            logging.ClearProviders();
            logging.AddConsole();
            if (hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment() == true)
                logging.AddDebug();
        })
        .ConfigureHostConfiguration(configurationBuilder =>
        {
            configurationBuilder.AddCommandLine(args);
        })
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, configApp) =>
        {
            var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
            Console.WriteLine(env.EnvironmentName);
        })
        .UseConsoleLifetime();

    return builder;
}

public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
     var host = CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                        {
                            services.Configure<HostOptions>(option =>
                            {
                                option.ShutdownTimeout = System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
                            });

                            services.AddLogging();

                            services.AddSimpleInjector(container, options =>
                            {
                                // Hooks hosted services into the Generic Host pipeline while resolving them through Simple Injector
                                options.AddHostedService<Worker>();

                                // Allows injection of ILogger & IStringLocalizer dependencies into application components
                                options.AddLogging();
                                // options.AddLocalization();
                            });
                        })
                        .Build()
                        .UseSimpleInjector(container);

     config.Build();
     await host.RunAsync();
}
```

I am using `UseConsoleLifetime` and docker to run the application, it runs, but i do not seem to be able to gracefully shutdown.

I gracefully send a stop signal to my application via the `docker stop` command in PowerShell.

However, unlike my console app where i press control+C, the app doesn't get this stop command and after 10 seconds is killed forcibly.

My questions are please:

1. How can i detect the docker shutdown command?
2. How can i register both methods of shutdown (via console or docker) depending on the method by which i am calling (at times I may debug directly in Visual Studio as a console, whereas mostly i would use via docker, but would be nice to auto-register for both scenarios).

**EDIT AND UPDATE**

I have seen replies, thank you, mentioning to trap on `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit`.

For my worker `BackgroundService` the interface is such that it has the function:

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
             logger.LogInformation("running at: {time} - stoppingToken {stoppingToken}", DateTimeOffset.Now, stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested);
             await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Using the `UseConsoleLifetime` whenever ctrl+c is sent, the stoppingToken is set.

When using the same code (including `UseConsoleLifetime` same code as is) within docker, the stoppingToken is not set.

Note i cant see that i have access to this token source in order to perform the cancellation.

If i register to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit` how can i use this to set the stoppingToken (as opposed to making my own stopping token source, as whilst can be done, would like to avoid if possible).

[image: docker stop]

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47474602/2501279)?

Comment: Looks good thank you, `Domain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit` can that run in parallel with `UseConsoleLifetime()` or any specific way to detect if running as console or via docker to account for either registration?

Comment: Not sure, but you can try subscribing to `System.Console.CancelKeyPress` event also.

Comment: You don't need to register for `ProcessExit` or any other event. `UseConsoleLifetime()` listens for Ctrl+C, SIGINT and SIGTERM - it already monitors process termination. When you run `docker stop` the SIGTERM is sent to the root process of the container. Is that your application or another one? How do you build and run the host? `.Build().RunAsync()` ? Something else?

Comment: What does your BackgroundService code look like? When termination is signalled, the `CancellationToken` passed through `ExecuteAsync` is signalled. Your code should monitor it and exit quickly if it's raised

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it was indeed with `await Build().RunAsync()` have updated my question to reflect the code. With RunAsync and also using `void Main()` and using `host.Run()`, unfortunatly with my code i do not get the stoppingToken set (where as the same code when run as a console works ok)

Answer (score 5):

`docker stop` sends the SIGTERM signal to the primary process in the container. To handle this and gracefully shutdown, you need to trap this signal and execute the appropriate termination code. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38291567/killing-gracefully-a-net-core-daemon-running-on-linux) SO question describes how you can attach an event handler that responds to this signal.

Note that if you don't trap this signal, docker will forcibly kill the container after a timeout (10 seconds by default).

To handle both, you can extract any clean up code you run to gracefully shutdown to a function, and invoke it from both handlers.

Comment: Thanks Orphid, once that signal is trapped any idea on how I can set the CancellationToken stoppingToken that is passed into the worker run function?