# Self hosted ASP.NET web services as gRPC server and client

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

We have an ASP.NET web service which is currently hosted on IIS. It acts as a client and as a server. The project is using .Net 4.6.1 framework. We want to abandon SOAP and use gRPC protocol, but IIS doesn't support HTTP2, so we can't create a server out of it.

I have found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35176091/how-should-a-grpc-service-be-hosted) that suggests that we make our application a windows service using Topshelf. Will this basically mean that we are writing our own hosting service? The application in question has a configuration in Global.asax which should be ran on application start, so it gets configured properly. It is using Autofac for dependency injections. Will we be able to run the `Global.asax` methods `Application_Start` and `Application_End` if we use Topshelf?

Comment: Your application is .Net Framework Asp.net, and not Asp.Net core, right ? The answer you are linking to is Asp.Net Core. You can't run a .Net framework asp.net application as a windows service.

Comment: The link is about .NET Core and even that is no longer necessary in .NET Core 3.0. You could always [create Windows Service application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer) in .NET Framework. You should *really, really, really* consider moving to .NET Core 3 though - that's the version with the full and ongoing gRPC and Worker/Service support. .NET Old 4.6 may or may not work and it's up to *you* to fix problems if it doesn't

Comment: @MikNiller you could always create and deploy Windows services in .NET Framework, going back to 2002 and .NET 1.0

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've created my fair share of windows services with or without Topshelf. Read my comment again, it is about running a ASP.NET application as a windows service.

Comment: Thank you very much guys. We will consider moving the project to .NET Core 3.