# How to Host a Code-First gRPC Service in Castle.Windsor?

Tags: c#, grpc, castle-windsor, protobuf-net, castle

does anyone have experience with hosting a Code-First gRPC Service using Castle.Windsor?
I've searched around but couldn't dig anthing up regarding this. Only for ASP.NET Core (using HostBuilder)

[How should a GRPC Service be hosted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35176091/how-should-a-grpc-service-be-hosted)
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/grpc/code-first?view=aspnetcore-7.0

I guess it's somehow possible, but there seems to be no Docs or anything about it whatsoever.